# What is a reason for using shift $((OPTIND-1)) after getopts?

Tags: bash

I realise  that shift moves the  array of  cli args n space to the left, and the default of n is 1. This means I  can assign the values the array to  existing varibles  using $1 shift inside a while loop. What I don't quite  understand is  why  it  is  used in  this context below. The input args have been assigned  to values already and deleting  shift $((OPTIND-1)) doesnt  change this fact.    Source:  http://linux.die.net/man/3/optind

```
while getopts ":h:a:fc" opt; do
    case $opt in
        h)
            print_help
            exit 0
            ;;
        a)
            aaaa=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        f)
            force=1
            ;;
        c)
            CLEAN=1
            ;;
        \?)
            echoerr "Invalid option -$OPTARG"
            print_help
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Comment: What if there are also positional parameters?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The shift removes the parameters processed by the `getopts` loop from the parameter list, so that the rest of the script can process the remainder of the command line (if any) with $1... in the usual manner, without concern for the number of options processed by `getopts`.

Consider a hypothetical script with the usage

```
frobble [-f] [-c] [-a hostname] filename ...
```

The `getopts` loop above takes care of parsing the `-f`,`-c` and `-a`, if they are present, but doesn't remove them from the argument list.  Which means that to get at your filename argument, you need to find out how many options were processed, and continue processing from there.  Conveniently, `getopts` tells you the index of the first unprocessed argument: the variable `OPTIND`.

And instead of messing with offsets and stuff, you can just discard the processed options, renumbering the rest of the arguments so your filename is always `$1`.

That is what `shift $((OPTIND-1))` does.

Comment: The `shift` syntax is overlooked here. `shift [n]` is a bash/sh builtin command that will shift the argument index by _n_. Thus, if your command has, for instance, 3 arguments, arg1, arg2, and arg3, $1 will correspond to arg1, $2 will correspond to arg2, etc. If you call `shift 2` in your script, $1 will now correspond to arg3.

Comment: @nucatus Not overlooked.  As the poster stated in the very first sentence of the question that they understood the syntax of `shift`, I saw no reason to re-explain the obvious.  But if you only read the answer, it may be useful to have it restated, so thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

1. The expression is normally found immediately after a `getopts` `while` loop. `$OPTIND` is the number of options found by `getopts`.
2. `OPTIND` gives the position of the next command line argument.
3. `shift` pops the first argument from the list of arguments.
4. `shift N` pops the first `N` arguments from the list of arguments.

**However, this short expression contains a syntax error.** This error has propagated throughout the interwebs. The correct syntax is:

```bash
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"
```

Expressions yielding values should be double-quoted, to guard against results containing embedded spaces

Comment: There is no need to double-quote the result of this arithmetic expansion. Also, the getops command declares OPTIND variable with the integer attribute set (declare -i OPTIND), which cannot contain embedded spaces as it is evaluated even if the $((..)) expansion is not used. Statement OPTIND="str ing" will throw a syntax error and OPTIND value will remain the same. (If the expression is invalid, Bash prints a message indicating failure to the standard error and no substitution occurs.) https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html